# Observer crashes/does not update Shiny/R

Tags: r, geolocation, shiny, leaflet

Working with shiny for R and leaflet for R/shiny

In my `ui.R` I have an element looking like this

```
radioButtons("startEnd",
    label = "Choose",
    choices = list("start" = 1,
    "end" = 2),
    selected = NA,
    inline = TRUE
)
```

Then, on my `server.R` side I want to store the coords of a click on the map, depending which `radioButton` is active.

```
# create reactive matrix that stores lat/lng from startpoint
startPoint <- reactiveValues()

# create reactive matrix that stores lat/lng from endpoint
endPoint <- reactiveValues()

observeEvent(input$myMap_click, {
    coords <- input$myMap_click
    if (input$startEnd == 1) {
        startPoint[["lat"]] <- coords$lat
        startPoint[["lng"]] <- coords$lng
    } else if (input$startEnd == 2) {
        endPoint[["lat"]] <- coords$lat
        endPoint[["lng"]] <- coords$lng
    } else {
        print("No Start- nor Endpoint selected")
    }
})
```

However, when I start my app and I click somwhere without having any `radioButton` selected, the app crashes with this error message:

> Warning: Unhandled error in observer: Argument has length 0
>   observeEvent(input$myMap_click)

When I select a `radioButton` and click then on the map, the app does not crash, but the reactive values do not get updated...
My output looks like this then

```
 observe({
      print("start")
      print(startPoint)
 })
```

> [1] "start"
>   $impl
>   
>     Public:
>       .allValuesDeps: environment
>       .dependents: environment
>       .label: reactiveValues8099
>       .namesDeps: environment
>       .setLabel: function
>       .values: environment
>       .valuesDeps: environment
>       clone: function
>       get: function
>       initialize: function
>       mset: function
>       names: function
>       self: environment
>       set: function
>       toList: function
>
> attr(,"class")
>   [1] "reactivevalues"
>   attr(,"readonly")
>   [1] FALSE

Whats going on? I do not understand that...

Comment: The first one is easy. `input$startEnd` has value `NULL` until a `radioButton` is selected. And the `if` statement tries `NULL == 1` which is not possible in R. Wrap some `if(!is.null(input$startEnd)){...}` around your code.

Comment: For the second one, the class `reactiveValues` is a special one. If you just print `startPoint`, you get all of the information that this class stores. This is not what you want. You want to print `list(lat = startPoint$lat, lng = startPoint$lng)`.